# Django accessing form fields dynamically in template

Tags: django, templates

I am trying to mimic the django admin's fieldsets functionality, to group form fields in my own view.

So I have a form in my template, and I have passed the fieldset list in my context data.

```
{% for fieldset in fieldsets  %}
    <fieldset class="module aligned">
        <h2>{{ fieldset.0 }}<h2>


        {% for field in  fieldset.1.fields %}
            <div>
            {{ form.field }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

    </fieldset>

{% endfor %}
```

The problem is the `{{ form.field }}` is treating field as a string, and not as the value stored in the variable. Is there a way to access this in the template, like `getattr()`.

Comment: Could you post `views.py`?

Comment: Are you trying to call `field` method/variable of `form` object? In that way yo can not do it. You must write a custom template filter, or maybe a template tag but otherwise you cant achieve what you want. [See docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: Ok, that's what I wanted to know, thanks.